# Why does the actorOf function **NOT** require a function input that has a *Actor<_>* as a parameter?

Tags: f#, akka.net

**Akka.Net:**

Why does the *actorOf* function **NOT** require a function input that has a *Actor<_>* as a parameter?

It appears that the *actorOf2* function DOES require a *Actor<_>* parameter.

**The context of how these functions are called are the following:**

```
let consoleWriterActor = spawn myActorSystem "consoleWriterActor" (actorOf Actors.consoleWriterActor)
let consoleReaderActor = spawn myActorSystem "consoleReaderActor" (actorOf2 (Actors.consoleReaderActor consoleWriterActor))

let consoleReaderActor (consoleWriter: IActorRef) (mailbox: Actor<_>) message = 
    ...

let consoleWriterActor message = 
    ...
```

The signature of *actorOf* is the following:

```
('Message -> unit) -> Actor<Message> -> Cont<'Message,'Returned>
```

The signature of *actorOf2* is the following:

```
(Actor<Message> -> 'Message -> unit) -> Actor<Message> -> Cont<'Message,'Returned>
```

**Conclusion:**

I am new to Akka.net. 
Thus, I don't understand why the "Actor<_>" parameter (which I believe represents a mailbox) would not be useful for the actorOf function.

Answer (score 0):

`actorOf2` function takes an `Actor<_>` parameter, which represents an actor execution context (from F# `MailboxProcessor` it's often called mailbox). It allows for things such as changing actor lifecycle, creating child actors or communicating with message sender.

However sometimes you may want to create actor, that is designed to work as a simple sink for your data i.e. processing the messages and push the result into some external service. This is where `actorOf` may be useful.